# Xcode 4.4.1 keep crashing on Storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I can't open my main Storyboard file with Xcode.
I updated to 4.4.1 without success. I tried to restore a previous version of my storyboard, but it doesn't open it. It crashes every time.

If I create a new storyboard file it opens it, but I don't want to start from scratch.

Here's a crash log:

```
Process:         Xcode [21518]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.4.1 (1488)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1488000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 9950605
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [294]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-09-04 18:59:51.627 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.1 (12B19)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          362662 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           225
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1725 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   17
Anonymous UUID:                      9730AF74-F1A3-49A6-BE6A-AB5A3B587E29

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4F1003
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSBadBitmapParametersException): Overflow allocating bitmap backing store.  Cannot back bitmap with 1152921504606846976 bytes per row, -9223372036854775808 height, and 1 planes.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff927166fe __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff981ae470 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff927164ec +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8d8b065f NSNewBitmapBackingStore (in AppKit)
  4  0x00007fff8d9fe301 +[NSCGImageSnapshotRep _lockFocusForCreatingSnapshot:withRect:context:hints:flipped:] (in AppKit)
  5  0x00007fff8dabfbee -[NSImageRep _newCGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:flipped:] (in AppKit)
  6  0x00007fff8d94f41b -[NSImageRep CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:] (in AppKit)
  7  0x00007fff8d9e75dd -[NSImageRep CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:flipped:] (in AppKit)
  8  0x00007fff8da6baa6 -[NSImage _newSnapshotRepForRep:rect:context:processedHints:] (in AppKit)
  9  0x00007fff8da0db98 -[NSImage _snapshotRepForRep:rect:context:processedHints:] (in AppKit)
 10  0x00007fff8d967442 __71-[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:]_block_invoke_0 (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff8d94ce26 -[NSImage _usingBestRepresentationForRect:context:hints:body:] (in AppKit)
 12  0x00007fff8d967269 -[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:] (in AppKit)
 13  0x000000010e8b2c8a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 14  0x000000010e8b3352 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 15  0x0000000106278ef8 DVTCGContextDrawBlockByPreservingState (in DVTKit)
 16  0x000000010e8b3270 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 17  0x000000010e8b1350 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 18  0x00007fff8d939a94 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] (in AppKit)
 19  0x00007fff8d9380f1 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 20  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 21  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 22  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 23  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 26  0x000000010613bee5 -[DVTReplacementView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in DVTKit)
 27  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8d938509 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff8d936122 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 37  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 38  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 39  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 40  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 41  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 42  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 43  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 44  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 45  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 46  0x00007fff8d937474 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 47  0x00007fff8d935b73 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] (in AppKit)
 48  0x00007fff8d93179d -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] (in AppKit)
 49  0x00007fff8d8fb703 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 50  0x00007fff900dbb81 __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
 51  0x00007fff926dd0c7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 52  0x00007fff926dd031 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 53  0x00007fff926b84a8 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 54  0x00007fff926b7dd2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 55  0x00007fff950db774 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 56  0x00007fff950db454 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 57  0x00007fff950db3a3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 58  0x00007fff8d8f7fa3 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 59  0x00007fff8d8f7862 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 60  0x00007fff8d8eec03 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 61  0x00007fff8d893656 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 62  0x0000000105ce3dc0 (in Xcode)
 63  0x0000000000000002

objc[21518]: garbage collection is ON
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96d39212 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91a40b34 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91a84dfa abort + 143
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000106a9d685 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:] + 506
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000106a9e300 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 603
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d8eed42 -[NSApplication run] + 836
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d893656 NSApplicationMain + 869
7   com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x0000000105ce3dc0 0x105ce2000 + 7616
```

Comment: Whats the code that causes the crash. Or: whats the last step you can walk through with the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to tell, but looking at your stack (lines 4-10) there is a problem with an image.  I would go into your application and make sure it is loading the image correctly.  If you are still having the problem, try removing images from the view that is causing the problem until you can figure out exactly which one is causing the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to remove all my images... It doesn't work! I deleted my storyboard and I created it from scratch. Now it works, but i'll never know why it crashed!